# No debug tracing using Django setting Debug = True

Tags: django

During development I had DEBUG = True and I got debug tracings. Then I switched to DEBUG = False for testing the 404 / 500 pages.

Now, after I switched back to DEBUG = True I get no tracings, only "Internal Server Error" message.

How do I get those debug tracings back?

Thanks
Martin Weberg

Comment: if you are running apache for example, you will need to reload it to see the changes in source code.

Comment: What is your server config like? (apache, nginx, etc?) or are you just using the built-in runserver? Either way you'll need to stop your server and start it again. I had an issue with using a restart command instead of stop/start and code in the settings.py was not updating

Comment: Sorry all of you... I did a search for "debug = False" in my projects folder and found it a second time further down in the settings.py file. Thank you all for the time you spent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you checking that DEBUG is set to True?  Try

python manage.py shell

At the python prompt enter

from django.conf import settings

settings.DEBUG

what is the result?

If it is False then Debug maybe getting reset in perhaps a local_settings.py file (or some other place). Then do a grep -r "DEBUG = False" * from the project directory.

If the result for settings.DEBUG was True, then either apache is loading the wrong wsgi, or wsgi is loading the wrong settings.py file.

Which settings.py file is wsgi using?

Comment: I found a second "debug = False" further down in the settings.py .... Thank you for pushing me in the right direction.

Comment: `import settings` is not the good way to import settings, use instead `from django.conf import settings`

Answer (score 1):

first check DEBUG setting from

```
$ python manage.py shell
In [1]: from django.conf import settings

In [2]: settings.DEBUG
Out[2]: True
```

`django.conf.settings` abstracts the concepts of default settings and site-specific settings; it presents a single interface. It also decouples the code that uses settings from the location of your settings.
[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code)

Answer (score 0):

try to enter invalid path. If 404.html will apear it means that somewhere DEBUG is still set to False, or like Uku Loskit wrote you have to reload server

**EDIT:**

1. Run django built-in server and see the results
2. print DEBUG at the end of settings.py

Comment: Now I double checked.

DEBUG = True I restarted Apache.

Now when I enter an invalid URL i get the 404.html message.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Give a chance to [The Python Debugger](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html), it is really simple, just import it and write pdb.set_trace() in the line you want to start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the DEBUG setting by doing:

```
python manage.py shell
import settings
print settings.DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have verified DEBUG is True at runtime and this is still happening, ensure you have not set `DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` This setting will cause you to not see debug tracebacks in the browser.